# C# Virtual Method Issue

Tags: c#, game-engine, gdi+

I'm currently programming a 2D Game Engine in C# using GDI+ and at the moment I'm trying to implement a component based structure.

The idea is that my GameObject class has a list of components. Each component can be completely different to the next.

I represented components by creating a Component class, which looks like this:

```
public class Component : BaseObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The game object this component is attached too.
    /// </summary>
    private GameObject gameObject = null;

    /*
     * Below I called the protected virtual methods from the "BaseObject" class.
     * The base object class only contains these 4 protected virtual methods. Nothing else.
     */

    public void Load()
    {
        OnLoad(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void Unload()
    {
        OnUnload(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        OnUpdate(this, new UpdateEventArgs(gameTime));
    }

    public void Render(GraphicsEngine graphicsEngine)
    {
        OnRender(this, new RenderEventArgs(graphicsEngine));
    }

    public GameObject GameObject
    {
        get { return gameObject; }
        set { gameObject = value; }
    }
}
```

In my game object class, every component that is within the components list gets updated and rendered like so:

```
    internal void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
            OnUpdate(this, new UpdateEventArgs(gameTime));

            // All components being updated
            components.ForEach(c => c.Update(gameTime));
    }
```

With all of that being said, I've created a SpriteComponent class, which is meant to render a simple 2D sprite, based on the game objects position, it's overrided render method looks like this:

```
    protected override void OnRender(object sender, RenderEventArgs e)
    {
        e.GraphicsEngine.DrawBitmap(bitmap, GameObject.Transform.Position);
        base.OnRender(sender, e);
    }
```

However for some reason this happens (This is the render method of the GameObject class):

```
    internal void Render(GraphicsEngine graphicsEngine)
    {
        if (Enabled)
        {
            // Rendering a sprite component like this works fine
            // Here I've created created a SpriteComponent inside the game object class to test it
            if(sprite != null)
            graphicsEngine.DrawBitmap(sprite.Bitmap, transform.Position);

            OnRender(this, new RenderEventArgs(graphicsEngine));

            // But rendering it using it's own method doesn't work
            //sprite.Render(graphicsEngine);

            // and this doesn't work properly either
            // components.ForEach(c => c.Render(graphicsEngine));
        }
    }
```

And here is a picture of the result when I either iterate through the components list and render it, or render the sprite component by it's self:

[image]

Comment: The code looks pretty fine for me. What exactly happens when you call sprite.Render(graphicsEngine) in your GameObject's Render method? Does it throw an exception? If you place a breakpoint in your Sprite's OnRender, will execution break on it?

Comment: @rs232 The screenshot at the bottom of post shows what happens when I call sprite.Render in the game objects render method. It's the same results to as if I were iterating through the components list and rendering it.

Comment: Hmm, but what is the expected result then? What do you get when you call graphicsEngine.DrawBitmap directly from your GameObject's Render method?

Comment: calling graphicsEngine.DrawBitmap directly from the render method, draws all sprites correctly and I end up with a complete map.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a slightest idea what is considered "correctly" and how a complete map should look in your case. Does it contain the same set of sprites but positioned differently? Do those sprite repeat/tile? Could you please be a little more specific on that?

Comment: @rs232 There are meant to be many more sprites, that make up entire room, with floor and walls and such. I've realised that for some reason some of the components gameObject members aren't being set to the correct game object... it's quite odd.

Comment: this means that the provided code is perfectly ok (as I was supposing earlier) and the core of the problem lies elsewhere, probably in the component's GameObject assigning/handling, right?

Comment: Well... You'd think so, but it seems to only be an issue when loading multiple game objects at once. So I think maybe the issue might lie in the map importer class

Answer (score 1):

I would look into you calling the `OnRender`. It is not best practice to call these event handlers. The has to be some other method you need to call which will invoke the `OnRender`.

Similar to `OnDraw` (Event handler) and `Update` (Invoke method)

Comment: I don't understand... you realise that these methods are my own?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did `override` wrong method, As I see you have override the `OnRender` 
While probably you calling `Render` method.

Try to make the `Render` method `virtual` and `override` it in child classes

Comment: The Render method executes the OnRender method